# INI file get section line by line

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have an `ini` file like this:

```
[section1]
line1
line2
[section2]
line3
line4
```

I want to read lines, but only from `[section1]` for example.
I need only the `line1` and `line2` as string.
Now it is running:

```
SET var=lines.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%var%) DO (
    CALL script.cmd %%a
)
```

It is a batch file, but I can't find a solution.
Every time when I want to use contents from `section2`, I need to use `lines2.txt`, but now I merged together (`ini` file above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a flag to toggle action (set the flag when the starting header is found, unset it, when the next header starts):

```
@echo off
set var=test.ini
set "flag="
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in (%var%) DO (
  if defined flag (
     echo %%a|find "[" >null && set "flag=" || (
       echo calling script.cmd with parameter %%a
     )
  ) else (
    if "%%a" == "[section1]" set flag=1
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you could use this two read the first two lines from the `section1`:

```
$content = Get-Content "Your_Path_here"
$section1Start = $content | Where-Object { $_ -match '\[section1\]'} | select -ExpandProperty ReadCount
$content | Select -Skip $section1Start -First 2
```

Comment: what if you don't know how many keys there are in this section?

Comment: Then you have to determine the position of the new section (same as section1start), substract section1start and section1end and pass it to the `-first` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend parsing the INI file properly, e.g. like this:

```
$inifile = 'C:\path\to\your.ini'
$ini = @{}

Get-Content $inifile | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Trim()
} | Where-Object {
  $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
} | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
    $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
    $ini[$section] = @{}
  } else {
    $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
    $ini[$section][$key] = $value
  }
}
```

Then you can access the elements of `section1` like this:

```
$ini['section1']['line1']
```

or (using dot-notation) like this:

```
$ini.section1.line1
```

You can also enumerate all elements of a section like this:

```
$ini['section1'].Keys
$ini['section1'].Values
```

or like this:

```
$ini['section1'].GetEnumerator()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ini file is with valid format this will set all lines in the wanted section in a list of variables starting with `[section1]`. It will handle comments also and will perform left trim on the lines.Uses only cmd internal commands so should be fast.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "file=test.ini"
set "section=[section1]"

set flag=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%# in ("%file%") do (
    set line=%%#
    ::trim
    for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("!line!") do set "line=%%a"
    set f=!line:~0,1!
    if "!f!" neq ";" (
        if !flag! equ 1 (
            for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("!line!") do (
            ::for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("%%#") do (
                set "!section!.%%a=%%b"
            )
        )

        if "!f!" equ "[" (
            if "!line!" equ "%section%" (
                set flag=1
            ) else (
                set flag=0
            )
        )       
    )
)

set %section%.
```