# How to store an array of hashtables in a text file and then call all of the values for a given key in each hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am using a text file as the backend for an application that I am developing. I first started off leaving the text file in a human-readable format but I decided that there was no sense in that figured it would be best to leave out formatting.

Where I am now in the backend dev process is creating a single-line hashtable with identical keys but different values for each entry. Seems logical and easy to work with.

Here is a mock-up of the entries in the text file:

```
@{'bName'='1xx'; 'bTotal'='1yy'; 'bSet'='1zz'}
@{'bName'='2xx'; 'bTotal'='2yy'; 'bSet'='2zz'}
@{'bName'='3xx'; 'bTotal'='3yy'; 'bSet'='3zz'}
```

As you can see, the keys for each entry are identical, however, the values are going to be different. (*The numerical and repetitious nature of the values are purely coincidental and put in place for the sake of a mock-up. Actual values will not be numerically-oriented and won't be repetitious as seen in the example.*)

I am able to access keys and values by typing:

```
$hash = Get-Content .\Desktop\Test.txt | Out-String | iex
```

which outputs:

```
Name                    Value
----                    -----
bName                   1xx
bTotal                  1yy
bSet                    1zz
bName                   2xx
bTotal                  2yy
bSet                    2zz
bName                   3xx
bTotal                  3yy
bSet                    3zz
```

What I ultimately want to do is gather each of the values for `bName`, `bTotal`, and `bSet` so that I can append each to a separate WinForms ComboBox. The WinForms part will be simple, I am just having a bit of an issue with getting the values from each hashtable in the text file.

I tried:

```
$hash.Values | ?{$hash.Keys -contains 'bName'}
```

but it just prints out every `$hash.Value` regardless of the `$hash.Key` match given in the pipe.

I understand that `$hash` is an array and I figured I may have to pipe out each iteration in a `foreach ($hash | %{})` loop but I'm not quite sure the correct way to do this. For example, when I try:

```
$hash | $_.Keys
```

or

```
$hash | $_.Values
```

it isn't treating each iteration like a hashtable.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I going about it in a convoluted way while there is a much easier way to accomplish this? I am open to all sorts of ideas or suggestions.

---

**As an afterthought**: It is kind of funny how often an obvious solution presents itself when you step away and divert your attention towards something else.

I went to grab lunch and I can't, for the life of me, begin to comprehend why I didn't realize that I could just very easily do this:

```
$hash.bName
```

or:

```
$hash.bTotal
```

or:

```
$hash.bSet
```

That will do exact as I was wanting to do. However, considering the answers provided, I may go a different route in terms of using an .ini file in CSV format rather than creating an array of hashtables.

Comment: Is it necessary to write your data to a file in this format?  Things would be easier if you could use a 'standard' format, csv for example.

Comment: @JasonBoyd There isn't a particular reason. I figured a hashtable would be easier to work with due to PowerShell's ability to format and separate the data intuitively. If CSV files can perform the work in an easier way, I'd use that instead. How would I go about accomplishing this using a CSV .txt file? How could I just grab data fields based on position in the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of storing hashtables in a text file is the [INI format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).

```
[hashtable1]
bName=1xx
bTotal=1yy
bSet=1zz

[hashtable2]
bName=2xx
bTotal=2yy
bSet=2zz

[hashtable3]
bName=3xx
bTotal=3yy
bSet=3zz
```

INI files are basically a hashtable of hashtables in text form. They can be read [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37746085/1630171):

```
$ht = @{}
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\hashtables.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Trim()
} | Where-Object {
  $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
} | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
    $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
    $ht[$section] = @{}
  } else {
    $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
    $ht[$section][$key] = $value
  }
}
```

and written like this:

```
$ht.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  '[{0}]' -f $_
  foreach ($key in $ht[$_].Keys) {
    '{0}={1}' -f $key, $ht[$_][$key]
  }
} | Set-Content 'C:\path\to\hashtables.txt'
```

Individual values in such a hashtable of hashtables can be accessed like this:

```
$ht['section']['key']
```

or like this:

```
$ht.section.key
```

---

Another option would be to store each hashtable in a separate file

`hashtable1.txt`:

```
bName=1xx
bTotal=1yy
bSet=1zz
```

`hashtable2.txt`.

```
bName=2xx
bTotal=2yy
bSet=2zz
```

`hashtable3.txt`:

```
bName=3xx
bTotal=3yy
bSet=3zz
```

That would allow you to import each file into a hashtable via [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx):

```
$ht1 = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\hashtable1.txt' | Out-String |
       ConvertFrom-Stringdata
```

Writing the files would basically be the same as above (there is no `ConverTo-StringData` cmdlet):

```
$ht1.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  '{0}={1}' -f $_, $ht[$_]
} | Set-Content 'C:\path\to\hashtables1.txt'
```

Comment: Now that is an awesome answer! I love getting something complex and going through it line-by-line and figuring it out. That's what makes this site great. It did take me a little bit to decipher the regexs because I don't use them regularly (no pun intended). I am a little confused on how to write to the hashtables. Say, for instance, I wanted to update a key value and just that. How exactly would I go about doing that using your example? I could byte-bang it out but I'd like to learn more about your given example, if you don't mind.

Comment: `$ht['key'] = 'newvalue'` will replace a value in a hashtable. If you need to replace a key/value pair you need to remove the existing entry and create a new one (`$ht.Remove('oldkey'); $ht['newkey'] = 'newvalue'`. To replace values or key/value pairs in a file just write the hashtable to the file as described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has built in csv handling so it makes it a good choice to use in this case.  So, assuming you had your data stored in a file in the standard csv format with headers:

```
"bName","bTotal","bSet"
"1xx","1yy","1zz"
"2xx","2yy","2zz"
"3xx","3yy","3zz"
```

Then you import your data like this:

```
$data = Import-Csv $path
```

Now you have an array of `PsCustomObject` and each header in the csv file is a property of the object. So if, for example, you wanted to get the `bTotal` of the second object you would do the following:

```
$data[1].bTotal
```

> 2yy

Comment: Looks like a no-mess, no-fuss solution on storing information in a text file. I will be making frequent updates to information and I will be creating and removing tables. I haven't played around with CSV files in the past but I worry that accessibility and ease of management are in lieu of lack of a consistent structure. I'll play around with it and see if it can hold up to the rough-and-tumble way I plan to use it. Cheers!

Comment: @Rincewind CSV is a good format if all your records have the same properties (even if some of them are empty).