# How to pass data from a text file to an object parameter in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to set application pool setting by reading settings from text file and setting it via powershell on my machine. But I am having trouble to set the `object[]` parameter. I have highlighted information in comments below for clarity.

```
#Content of text file: @(@{ name="Test"; autoStart="1"; startMode="1" },@{ name="Test2"; autoStart="1"; startMode="1" }) 
 
$file_data= Get-Content "C:Files\Template.txt"

#The code works when doing like this, it gives $AppPoolToWarmup.name as Test1 and Test2
Object[] $AppPoolToWarmup = @(@{ name="Test"; autoStart="1"; startMode="1" },@{ name="Test2"; autoStart="1"; startMode="1" }) 

#But I want to make it work in this way. Right now $AppPoolToWarmup.name gives Blank
Object[] $AppPoolToWarmup = $file_data

Import-Module WebAdministration
write-host "INFO: Pools: " $AppPoolToWarmup.name
foreach($ap in $AppPoolToWarmup){
    #write-host "INFO: Pools:" $ap.name
    
$name = $ap.name
    if(Test-Path "IIS:\AppPools\$name"){
        $autoStart = $ap.autoStart
        $startMode = $ap.startMode
        Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$name" -Name autoStart -Value $autoStart  
        Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\$name" -Name startMode -Value $startMode
    
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing _data_ and _code_. Rename `Template.txt` to `Template.ps1` and invoke it as a script instead

Comment: Assuming you are trying to read a file containing an array of hashtables, we need to understand the format the file is in.  Here is an example of someone saving an array of hashtables, is this the format of your source data?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074471/how-to-store-an-array-of-hashtables-in-a-text-file-and-then-call-all-of-the-valu

Comment: @Darin, thanks. This post helped me out in sorting out my issue.

Comment: Rohit Singh, glad it helped!